# EWS findFolders throws : An internal server error occurred. The operation failed., IdAndSession.MailboxSession: session is not IMailboxSession

Tags: azure, office365, exchange-server, exchangewebservices

I'm trying to find all folder is in EWS Public Folders (starting from Public folders root) and getting this strange exception :

An internal server error occurred. The operation failed., IdAndSession.MailboxSession: session is not IMailboxSession

Googling didn't provide any helpful information.

Update (06 Dec 2018): issue disappeared after few day and now after 6 month back again, tried to talk with Microsoft Office 365 Engineer by chat, he said that seems that it's Office 365 bug, but not sure even if it'll be fixed. Very strange.

Thanks

Comment: What does your code look like ? You can't do a deep traversal on a Public Folder Store

Comment: I know that I can't do deep traversal, this is a not new code, and it still working fine for other customers, but it started to throw this for some and this is growing. My contact at Microsoft suggested to ask here, as he never saw this message before.

Comment: We got the same error too.  Code has been live for 6 months or so.  We first observed the error on Feb 22nd.  We get this when we call `FindFolders(WellKnownFolderName.PublicFoldersRoot, folderName, new FolderView(1))`

Comment: Well, seems that this was a bug from MS, as issue disappeared on some customers. No any explanation from MS.

Comment: We're doing a o365 backup with Veeam, and our public folder mailbox is generating this issue as well. I have also no further feedback yet.

Comment: There's no confirmation from Microsoft that it's going to be fixed soon.

Comment: It seems to be fixed now during the night. My version has changed from {15.20.1446.017} to {15.20.1446.019}

Comment: Well, still can't confirm as I see it in our logs, but they add a new issue, we see many errors , starting from yesterday : "There's no mailbox with such guid" for mailboxes that are really exists.

Comment: @Bhargav Rao, seems that this topic is useful for other, very sad that you voted to put it on hold.